# I can't find wix setup editor to add files to the installer in Visual studio 2015

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, wix

I can't find wix setup editor to add files to the installer in Visual studio 2015.
there is no option of wix setup editor to add the resources and file.

Comment: Regular WiX is source code-based. Did you use a third party editor previously? You can also use heat.exe to auto-generate WiX source code. I have several answers on this that you can search for, or you can provide more information on what you are looking for.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Thank you for the help.. really Appreciated. You Explained Every thing in detail. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't find wix setup editor to add files to the installer in Visual
> studio 2015

**Actually**, adding a new source file to wix project is different from other projects. Right-click on wix project and you cannnot add a new item resource file.

If you want these files shown on the **solution explorer**, you could add the resource files on the physical project folder path and then

Right-click on the wix project-->`Add`-->`Existing Item`-->select the resources files into your project.

**However**, the actual way to add resource files into wix package is to use Encoding method:

using two elements: a `<Component>` element to specify an atomic unit of installation and a `<File>` element to specify the file that should be installed.

You can refer to [this document to add a File To Your Installer](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/add_a_file.html).

**Solution**

Add these node in `Product.wxs` file:

```
<Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
             
    <Component Id="tests.xml" Guid="86239B6E-FD56-4CB4-938F-0CD84AF85FAC">
        <File Id="tests.xml" Source="xxx\tests.xml(the path of the file)" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

**Besides**, I think you use [Wax vs extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.Wax) in VS2015. If you use this extension, you can set these resource files on **Wix Setup Editor**.

To add resource files, you should create those resource files on the target project's solution explorer, you can and then you can select them in  **Wix Setup Editor**.

[image].

**Also**, please make sure that the files's **Build Action** is set to `Content` and **Copy to Output Directory** to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

[image]

**Then**, click this option to add it into wix package.

[image]

**After that**, it will add into `Product.wxs` file automatically.

[image]

**In addition**, you can refer to [this document about how to use Wix Setup Editor](https://github.com/tom-englert/Wax).

Comment: This Solve your problem. Rep++